# Monadic excerise Haskell. I can't deal with that

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write my function which extract numbers from string, for example:

```
"321 43 123 213" -> [321, 43, 123, 3212]
"dsa" -> Error
"123 da" -> Error
```

And I would like to do it using readEither and in monadic way ( I try to understand monads). My attemption:

```
import Text.Read

unit :: Either String [Int]
unit = Right []

extractInt :: String -> Either String [Int]
extractInt s =  helper (words s) where
    helper (h:t) = (bind readEither h) . (helper t)
    helper [] = Right []

bind :: (String -> Either String Int) -> String -> (Either String [Int] -> Either String [Int])
bind f x z = bind' (f x) z where
    bind' (Left s) _ = Left s
    bind' (Right i) (Right l) =  Right (l ++ [i])
    bind' (Left s) _  = Left s
```

1. Please help me solve my problem.
2. Please say something my solution.
3. Please say my how to do it correctly. ;)

Error:

```
    Couldn't match expected type `a0 -> Either String [Int]'
                with actual type `Either a1 [t0]'
    In the return type of a call of `Right'
    Probable cause: `Right' is applied to too many arguments
    In the expression: Right [1]
    In an equation for `helper': helper [] = Right [1]
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Comment: When learning Haskell, but type signatures on *everything*. What do you intend the type of `helper` to be? The equation for the `(h:t)` case has a different type than the equation for the `[]` case, hence the error.

Comment: What resources are you using to learn Haskell? Would you like pointers to other sources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want "something with >>=" your helper function should look like:

```
helper [] = Right []
helper (w:ws) = readEither w >>= \i -> fmap (i:) (helper ws)
```

Explanation: Clearly, for an empty list of words, we want an empty list of integers. For a nonempty list, we do `readEither` on the first word, which gives us an `Either String Int`. The bind (>>=) will pass the resulting integer to the function on the right hand side, but only if the result was `Right` If it was `Left` this is the overall result of the helper.

Now, the function on the right hand side of (>>=) applies the `helper` to the remaining words. As we know, this will result in `Either String [Int]`. Then it prepends the integer that resulted from conversion of the first word to the list in the `Right` result, if there is one. If, however, `helper` returned a `Left` value, the `fmap` won't change anything, and so this will be the overall result.

So the 2nd line with the (>>=) expands approxiamtely to the following code:

```
case readEither w of
    Left err  -> Left err
    Right int -> case helper ws of
        Left err -> Left err
        Right ints -> Right (int:ints)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the mapM function to monadically map over the words:

```
extractInt :: String -> Either String [Int]
extractInt s = mapM readEither (words s)
```

If any one call to readEither happens to return Left, then the function will do so too. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking a "raw" solution -> I mean using `>>=`

Comment: This solutions is the most concise one. You could probably replace `mapM` with something that uses `>>=` but... why?

Comment: because I don't understand monad and I do my best to understand it :)

Comment: Ah. I see! That's of course a good enough reason. Ingo seems to have that covered for you =)